# ViewModel lifetime when using a required Intent/Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-viewmodel

Problem: my ViewModel is being destroyed because I have to start another Activity while it's still needed. (It's unavoidably a new (Android-provided) Activity.)

Background: I have an application that is managing the interaction between several data sets. It uses a ViewModel as a performance cache because the data can be slow to access (as in potentially 10s of seconds). No critical data is stored in the ViewModel, but performance would be unacceptable without the cache. The original data is on the file system.

The ViewModel works exactly as expected unless I test aggressively and turn on the Developer Option "Don't Keep Activities" as a way of simulating memory starvation. From lots of logging I'm quite sure what's happening (details below). My question is if I'm missing an alternative to the ones I have thought of.

Scenario:

1. App starts up and loads the ViewModel and starts Activity A. (AppCompatActivity to be precise.)
2. User interacts and decides to change a directory containing some (not all) of the cached data. To do that requires launching a built-in-to-Android Activity (D) "for result" (to get the new directory name). Code for that below.
3. If "Don't Keep Activities" is *not* set: the directory selection works normally and the ViewModel survives. (Equivalently: the Activity is not destroyed.)
4. If "Don't Keep Activities" *is* set (or the system decides to terminate the Activity while the user is finding the new directory): The Activity A is destroyed just after the new Activity's (D) `onCreate` finishes, and the ViewModel's `onCleared` is called.

(This testing is on Oreo, but I doubt it matters.)

Here's the intent that starts the new Activity. This is apparently the standard way of finding a file or directory, and works fine (along with 
`onActivityResult`) to get the new directory.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED",true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_DIR_LOOKUP);
```

I've experimented with another Activity (call it B), where I own the code, which has the same problem, and cannot find a way to keep the ViewModel from being cleared in (4) above. In the case of the directory search (D), it's not even an option to modify it. It would have to be something before the directory search intent was started.

In an Activity of my own (B), I've tried using `isFinishing()` in the ViewModel's `onDestroy()` to skip `super.onDestroy`, with the unsurprising result that the system throws an error that `super.onDestroy()` wasn't called. I also tried having B's `onCreate` get the ViewModel from A (successfully, it's the same address), but A's `onCleared` is still called just after B's `onCreate` finishes (I was hoping for a reference counter). (This is confirmed by log messages.)

I don't see a way to keep the ViewModel from being destroyed when A is destroyed in case 4 above. Fixing that would be an ideal solution. Converting the ViewModel to a classical singleton should work. Other than saying "don't do that" to "Don't Keep Activities", is that my best choice?

If I do go with the singleton, is there a better way to see the `onCleared` event (for when I do want to destroy the ViewModel) than a hack involving a dummy ViewModel. `onDestroy` is a bit too soon to be useful.

**A Week Later**

The comments, although useful, don't really address the underlying problem that "canned" Activities don't play nicely with ViewModel. I was hoping that I had just missed something, but apparently not, and I'll have to work around what seems to me to be a design bug.

I think I'm seeing a somewhat different-in-detail, but related, problem on Pie: the "canned" Activity doesn't honor the current rotation (as it did in all previous versions) (yes, the same activity as in the example code). That's easily fixed inside the Activity, but requires modifying it, something I'm trying to stay away from, particularly for that Activity, since it's likely to change release-to-release.

Comment: 'Don't keep activities' doesn't simulate memory pressure like you think it does since Android only reclaims memory by [killing processes, not components](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/who-lives-and-who-dies-process-priorities-on-android-cb151f39044f). Anywhere you cache data in memory would be cleared under memory pressure.

Comment: Singletons aren't always bad as long as they're not abused (e.g. using them to break loose coupling between app layers) and you're careful with memory leaks (e.g. using Singletons to store contexts).  That said - does your cache have to be in memory?  Any reason why you can't use local storage (e.g. files, shared preferences or sqlite?)

Comment: have you ever solved this one?

Comment: No. For other reasons I ended up going back to a singleton. (I needed async task (background) access to the same data.)